# How do I create a queue for the use of web controls so only one user can see them at a time?

Tags: queue, controls, websocket, arduino

I'm working on Arena of little robots, using an AJAX/PHP frontent, Websockets to send commands  to an arduino, and the arduino sending IR commands to a robot.  The user views the robots via a network camera feed.

Right now, if you go to the website, it's a free for all.  There are two robots with separate control buttons, but many people can load the site simultaneously and click buttons, meaning nobody has exclusive control over a robot.

I am not looking to have people register and create a username/password, but I would like to have the site require them to enter a Nickname when they connect.  Once they enter a nickname, they can choose to take control of a robot if nobody is waiting, and the controls will be revealed.  (If user #2 now want to control that robot, the site will show him that user 1 has control, and he may place his name on the queue.  (I imagine i'd give people 45 seconds to a minute of control if others are waiting)

I know my way around PHP and javascript a bit, but I'm not sure how to approach this.  Do I need to use a mySQL database to keep track of the queue and lock/unlock status of the controls?

Thanks!

TL/DR I need to create a queue, so two users can't access the same set of buttons on a website at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use cookies for the "user identification" where you can save a timestamp. This either will unique identify the user and also will give u an idea about the queue of users. If you mind about the cookies hacking, you should encrypt that timestamp.

Using this procedure, you dont need to ask for a nickname neither use databases.

Also you can provide a time window access checking the difference of times between the "cookie timestamp and the "actual time" every time the signal is sent.